# How to create an initial value in an array in Angular and display that value in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a form with an append new row function. I can create a new row dynamically but my problem is I can't display the initial value in my textboxes.

Here's some of my code:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="product_list">
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="productList">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hovered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Product Name</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Quantity</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Price</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Subtotal</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewRow()">Add Row</button></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="value in product.item">
                    <td class="text-left">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <input type="number" ng-model="item.quantity" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <input type="number" ng-model="item.price" class="form-control text-right" value="{{ value.price }}" />
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ item.price * item.quantity | currency }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeRow($index)">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </td>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-left">
                        <label>Subtotal: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" value="{{ total() | currency }}" readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var appList = angular.module('product_list', []);

    appList.controller('productList', function($scope){

        $scope.product = {
            item: [
            {
                product_name: 'Test name 1',
                quantity: 5,
                price: 99.9,
            }
            ]
        };

        $scope.addNewRow = function() {

            $scope.product.item.push({
                product_name: '',
                quantity: 1,
                price: 0
            });

        }

        $scope.removeRow = function(index) {
            $scope.product.item.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $scope.total = function() {

            var total = 0.00;

            angular.forEach($scope.product.item, function(item){
                total += item.quantity * item.price
            });

            return total;

        }

    });

</script>
```

Here's the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/6vAVPw?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the variables mismatched, in here you use `value` as the repeated item:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in product.item">
```

But then you use the item as `item`, so just change your `value in product.item` to `item in product.item`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in product.item">
```

Also notice on line 44 of the HTML your have invalid html, change the `</td>` to `</tr>`

The last small thing to notice is that your item variable's name is called `product_name` in your objects, but you assign the `item.name` to your `ng-model`. So also update your first textfield to `ng-model=item.product_name`

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XTcYz9Qfb6Yqe8LZ4MTx?p=preview)

Comment: Ok it's working thanks for some correction in my code. I am still learning Angular as of now and sometimes I am confused with some of it's functions. As of now I need to check my variable naming to avoid some errors. :)

Comment: If you think this answer has answered your question please mark it as so :)

Comment: Yeah I still need to wait for 4 mins. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your use different variable name in ng-repeat and ng-model

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in product.item">
```

Since you use ng-model="**item**.name", just replace **value** with **item**

like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in product.item">
```